# How to list all keybinding include two combine key binding?

Tags: key-bindings

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580505/how-to-find-all-vim-mappings-starting-with-control-key

I check this link. use the way like this:

```
:redir @a    redirect output of next command to register a
:map         list mappings
:redir END   end redirection
:vnew        edit new buffer in vertical window
:put a       put content of register a
:v/<C-/d     delete all lines not matching '<C-'
```

I also check this link cant find it either
[https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/%7Efine/Tech/vi.html)

And get the maps, but I cant find the `ctrl+w, ctrl+v`(which will vertical split the window)keybinding in this list, so how to list them all?

Comment: `<C-W><C-V>` isn't listed at the page you link to because that's a list of vi keybindings, and `<C-W><C-V>` is a *Vim* command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> isn't a mapping: it's a normal mode command.

Mappings are set up using the various [`:map`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-commands) commands by your Vim configuration and your plugins. Normal mode commands are built into the Vim executable.

There's no command you can use to output them all, but they are listed at [`:help index`](https://vimhelp.org/index.txt.html#index) and they have individual documentation in the help which you can find using a [standardised syntax](https://vimhelp.org/usr_02.txt.html#help-summary).

So for your <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>, you would use the command: [`:help CTRL-W_CTRL-V`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_CTRL-V).